# Return different values for different input mocking arguments

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I encountered a situation where I need to return different values when there is a change in the input, both return value and input parameters are `String`.

```
    MethodA.getProperty("", "", "A");
    MethodA.getProperty("", "", "B");
```

The Mockito code I am trying to implement is like

```
Mockito.when(MethodA.getProperty(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("Apple")
Mockito.when(MethodA.getProperty(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("Banana")
```

I should get `Apple for A, Banana for B`.

please help me on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the argument while mocking to return specific values.
Example:

```
Mockito.when(MethodA.getProperty(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(), ArgumentMatchers.argThat(x -> x.equals("A")))).thenReturn("Apple")
Mockito.when(MethodA.getProperty(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(), ArgumentMatchers.argThat(x -> x.equals("B")))).thenReturn("Banana")
```